# Transform conditions into questions

Tags: nlp

I have a set of conditions in English that I would like to transform into questions with yes/no answers. Something like this:

- "when we get 2k customers" > "did we get 2k customers?"
- "if we end up using XYZ" > "did we ended up using XYZ?"
- "after we get 2k customers" > "did we get 2k customers?"

I can write transformation myself for a limited subset of questions but I'm wondering if there are any libraries / services I could use to have a solution that is more generic.

Any thoughts or suggestions on what else to consider for this task will be much appreciated.

This is my first time doing something NLP related but I have plenty of coding experience.

Thank you!

Comment: Your requirement seems strange.  Where are you getting the conditions from?  For example, how would you programmatically generate "if we end up using XYZ"?  It seems that if you can generate that you can generate the question "did we end up using XYZ?".  Have you read Michael Heilman's doctoral dissertation on question generation (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/mheilman/questions/)?

Comment: Brian, those conditions will be entered by the user (I would just extract them from the text). At some point later I want to ask user if those conditions occurred hence the question (I could just say "Is statement below true: xxxx" but that's not as cool :). Thank you for the link, I will definitely read that.